# Angularjs ng-repeat track by $index не ускоряет перерисовку

Tags: angularjs

у меня есть div элементы со сложной структурой каторые рисуюсьтся с помщью ng-repeat,примерно так

```
<div ng-repeat="item in data track by item.id">...</div>
```

Kогда элементы много рисование занимает много времени, я использвал бесконечную прокрутку для решение этой проблемы, но есть такой функционал, ползватель может добавить или удалить элементы, тогда обновляется данные в массиве

```
$scope.data = response.data;
```

и тогда весь контент перерисовается снова, которое занимает очень много времени, track by не помогает, есть ли другиe идеи, как повысить произвовадительность, заранее спасибо.

Comment: сколько именно может быть элементов? на сколько сложная структура?

Comment: после 20 элементов уже замедляет, есть много привязок

Comment: @K-sS-k, привязки изменяются сами по себе? или только когда меняется `data`?

Comment: @Grundy привязки изменяются когда пользователь редактирует элементи, или когда добавляется/удаляется элементи, то есть очень часто вызывается $digest

Answer (score 0):

Естественно, при удалении, добавлении и перестановке существующих объектов использование `track by $index` только замедлит работу по сравнению с `track by item.id`.

Comment: @Qwertiy track by $index и track by item.id работают одинаково для меня, ооочень медленно, когда число элементов 50, это занимает примерно 3-4с.